# Blank Theme for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to build a new WordPress site form scratch. So I guess I need a blank theme to do that. I need to know where I can find such a theme like that, and I need a tutorial that can help me to create my first WordPress theme from scratch.

I'm new in that world. So please I need your help.

Comment: I would advice in get your hands on a copy of the amazing [Wordpress Book](http://digwp.com/book/) - It will help you with your theme and all settings you will need to make :)

Comment: how do you it good? did you try it?

Comment: the book helps you throughout the chapters making a theme, the Theme [ClubeHouse](http://themeclubhouse.digwp.com/) and yes, I have it :)

Comment: Thanks, I will take your advice. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

**If you're starting with no WP knowledge, I believe you're better off modifying a blank theme than you are creating one from scratch.**

Here is a great [tutorial](http://themeshaper.com/2009/06/22/wordpress-themes-templates-tutorial/) I used when I started doing custom themes. The HTML is getting outdated semantically, but it will teach you all working parts of a WP theme.

As a starter theme I use [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/boilerplate) which is full of quality HTML5 and additional features like file caching, cross-browser readiness, mobile device readiness, and file caching, to name a few. Also it's got a minimal default styling.

You may also find [the wordpress site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) helpful. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks a lot. but I have a good knowledge in WP. I'm newbie in doing WP theme from scratch.

Comment: Well maybe you'll find the tutorial and blank theme useful, cuz that's what you asked for ;)

Comment: if you mean the tutorial you sent, it's really a great resource. Thanks a lot.

Comment: if someone else also could help, it will be great.

Answer (score 0):

starting with twentyten or twentyeleven isn't a bad option either.

Whatever theme you choice make it a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).
It may seem like something complex at first but it will make things easier along the way.

Comment: I agree with you about child theme, and I know how to do it and I already did it before, thanks. I need to make a new theme, just like the theme they sell it, or they publish it for free.

Answer (score 0):

Theme Hybrid has a great blank theme: http://themehybrid.com/themes/skeleton

Answer (score 0):

I have a starter theme on github that was originally based off html5 boilerplate that you can check out.. https://github.com/FernE97/html5-blank-slate